# Jenkins groovy pipeline simple inheritance glitch

Tags: inheritance, jenkins, intellij-idea, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to call the protected method of a parent class from a child class within a groovy script in a jenkins pipeline.  Jenkins crashes and says : "**groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: _parentValue for class: Child**".

However, if I run the exact same code in Intellij IDEA, it works fine.  I have no idea why this doesn't work in Jenkins.  Can someone help ?

Code :

```
public class Parent
{
    private int _parentValue

    public Parent()
    {
        _parentValue = 0
    }

    protected void Increment()
    {
        _parentValue = _parentValue + 1
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent
{
    public void IncrementFromChild()
    {
        // call parent method
        Increment()
    }
}

// Instantiate and call child method
def child = new Child()
child.IncrementFromChild()
```

Stacktrace:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: _parentValue for  class: Child
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.getProperty(DefaultInvoker.java:33)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
at Parent.Increment(WorkflowScript:12)
at Child.IncrementFromChild(WorkflowScript:20)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:25)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the CPS-transformation kills the inheritance in shared libraries. Which is very sad indeed.
See the last comment from Andrew Bayer [here.](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47355?jql=text%20~%20%22inherit%20class%22)

I am not sure, but maybe the @NonCPS-annotation could help in some cases.